# VS2012 : where is custom toolbar command SyncWithActiveDocument?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, command, synchronization, toolbar

In Visual Studio 2012, you can create customized toolbars and edit their contents (usually button shortcuts to some IDE commands).
I would like to add the SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument command to one of my toolbars, but cannot find it in the list of commands available for addition to the toolbar. In which category is it located? Or is it a command not supported by the toolbar system?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use SyncWithActiveDocument as a command - it is a manual sync that is only active when turning off "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" in Project and Solutions -> General.
Looking at it this way, is like trying to add auto-sync to a toolbar.